# Get the type of the bound property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

This question has been asked a few times on SO (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280388/get-underlying-data-type-of-binding) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548596/can-i-get-the-type-of-a-bound-object-in-c-wpf-even-if-the-bound-value-is-nul)), but those are some older questions and there is no answer for it without using reflection. So, I just want to ask it again to see if things have changed and whether we now have something to access this. It is possible that it is something connected with the core functionality of binding that is preventing Microsoft to implement it, but I wanted to give it a go.

I should be able to to that from within the `TextBox` control. I am getting the binding like this:

```
Binding bind = GetBindingExpression(TextProperty)?.ParentBinding;
```

but don't see anything there that would help me to get the source property type.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed really. You can get a reference to the *source* using either the `Source` property of the binding or the `DataContext` of the `TextBox`:

```
Type sourceType = bind.Source?.GetType();
if (sourceType == null)
    sourceType = DataContext?.GetType();
```

But to get the type of the property that you are binding to, you will have to use reflection:

```
Type propertyType = sourceType.GetProperty(bind.Path.Path).GetType();
```

WPF does (still) use reflection to resolve the property values.

Comment: I think you have a little typo: you must write `Type propertyType = sourceType.GetProperty(bind.Path.Path).PropertyType;`. Otherwise you will always get `RuntimePropertyInfo` as property type.